# How to collect tkinter Entry information and enter into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I want to take information from a lot of tkinter Entry boxes and place then in a dictionary to be passed into a different function. I want the key to be the variable (entry) name and the value to be the text that is stored in the entry box. I am able to collect all of the information but the dictionary keys are not correct. The keys make reference to the Entry but I want the key to be the variable name so that I can later pass it into a regex. This is the code that I have used so far.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ExApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Build the container
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(column = 0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        tlabel = tk.Label(self, text='This is just a test')
        tlabel.pack()

        pdc1 = tk.Entry(self)
        pdc1.pack()

        pdc2 = tk.Entry(self)
        pdc2.pack()

        pdc3 = tk.Entry(self)
        pdc3.pack()

        pdc4 = tk.Entry(self)
        pdc4.pack()

        self.entries = [pdc1, pdc2, pdc3, pdc4]

        testbutton = tk.Button(self, text = 'test',
                               command= lambda: print(self.collect_entries(self.entries)))
        testbutton.pack()

    def collect_entries(self, list = []):
        self.outputs = {}
        for entry in list:
            self.outputs[entry] = entry.get()
        return self.outputs

app = ExApp()

app.mainloop()
```

This is just a test script but my actual one contains a lot more entries. it ends up with having a huge number of variables being passed into another function but I think that it could be achieved with a single dictionary.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the names you have to store them as strings.  For instance in a list of Tuples (name, entry).  Then you can create a dictionary from the names and the content of the entry for that name.  With dict comprehension that is a one liner actually:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, _controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        tk.Label(self, text='This is just a test').pack()

        self.entries = list()
        for name in ['pdc1', 'pdc2', 'pdc3', 'pdc4']:
            entry = tk.Entry(self)
            entry.pack()
            self.entries.append((name, entry))

        tk.Button(
            self,
            text='test',
            command=lambda: print(self.collect_entries())
        ).pack()

    def collect_entries(self):
        return {name: entry.get() for name, entry in self.entries}
```

Comment: That works perfectly and will really make my script much shorter. Thank you.